# SQL, select from two tables based on a third, which references them

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mariadb, dbeaver

Just starting with SQL and the first all-nighter is already here.

I have three tables:

```
student (student_id, first_name, last_name)
course (course_id, name)
exam (ref_to_student_id, ref_to_course_id, score)
```

How do I make a select statement and list out student name, last name and course name, for all cases where achieved exam score was > X ?

This is my best shot:

```
SELECT last_name FROM student WHERE student_id IN 
 (SELECT ref_to_student_id FROM exam WHERE score > 50)
UNION ALL
SELECT name FROM course WHERE course_id IN
 (SELECT ref_to_course_id FROM exam WHERE score > 50)
```

It's faulty, because I get:

```
last_name
last_name
name
name
name
```

and there's no way of telling exactly which student scored above X on which exam/course.

In my mind, something like this:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, name
FROM student, course
WHERE student_id, course_id
IN (SELECT ref_to_student_id, ref_to_course_id FROM exam WHERE score > 50)
```

would produce something like this:

```
John Doe Chemistry
Jane Dove English
...
```

But, it only produces a notification about an error in the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join these tables, not `union` them:

```
SELECT last_name, first_name, name, score
FROM   student s
JOIN   exam e ON s.student_id = e.ref_to_student_id
JOIN   course c ON e.red_to_course_id = c.course_id
WHERE  score > 50
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use inner join between tables like this:

```
SELECT s.first_name AS first_name, s.last_name AS last_name, c.name AS course_name
FROM student s
INNER JOIN exam e ON e.ref_to_student_id = s.student_id
INNER JOIN course ON c.course_id = e.ref_to_course_id
WHERE e.score > 50;
```

Answer (score 1):

Friend, try this:

```
SELECT s.first_name, s.last_name, c.name
FROM exam e
JOIN student s ON s.student_id = e.ref_to_student_id
JOIN course c ON c.course_id = e.ref_to_course_id
WHERE e.score > 50
```

I hope to help you!